# Can someone help me with my python integer error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a simple binary search algorithm and I keep getting this error:

> 'int' not subscriptable

```py
while not found and firstPos <= lastPos:
    midPos = (int(firstPos + lastPos)/2)

    if searchNumber == lastPos[midPos]:
        found = True

    else:
        if searchNumber < lastPos[midPos]:
            lastPos = midPos - 1
        else:
            firstPos = midPos + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the code:

```
lastPos[midPos]
```

Here lastPos is a number. It is not possible to subscript a number. According to your logic your code should be something like:

```
if searchNumber == data[midPos]:
    found = True

else:
    if searchNumber < data[midPos]:
        lastPos = midPos - 1
    else:
        firstPos = midPos + 1
```

This is assuming, the array you are searching is named **data**. Use whatever your array name is.